# c# text editor modeling a list

Tags: c#, .net, html, text, editor

I am trying to create a text editor that is a front end for a list of strings of text. The user can make changes in the text editor and I want to be able to push the changes back to the appropriate element in the list.
Assuming this is the list

```
List<string> element;
element.Add("I was walking one morning,");
element.Add(" all of the sudden it started to rain,");
element.Add(" I opened my umbrella and looked for the closest coffee shop.");
element.Add(" After few blocks I was sheltered enjoying my morning coffee.");
```

it should display as regular text in the editor:

> I was walking one morning, all of the sudden it started to rain, I opened my umbrella and looked for the closest coffee shop. After few blocks I was sheltered enjoying my morning coffee.

so when the user makes changes to " looked for the closest " I want to be able to tell that he is making changes to element[2].

I also need to store more information about the individual elements ( formatting and other things), hence the use of List.

I looked into HTML editors and tried wrapping each sentence in a div, but when the user makes changes, the HTML editor merges the div or deletes it. so that generates extra work.

I was thinking about RTF but was reading online that there was no set standard.

I am flexible with implementation of the List and the other information.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

much appreciated.

Comment: If you need to store extra information about the sentences, consider creating a `Sentence` class and expose necessary methods/properties. Using a list of strings is not going to give you the functionality you seek (not easily anyway).

Comment: I don't understand. "I was walking one morning," is not a sentence. It ends in a comma, so it's part of a longer sentence. If you're actually splitting by sentence then you could try and do something clever with `text.Split(new[] {'.','!','?'})`. Then as long as no one deletes your full stops, or inserts a new sentence, you can track changes. Please clarify your requirements so we can help.

Comment: I would eventually create the class, it is the natural progression, but I am trying to figure out the editor concept before investing time in other areas.

Comment: James, I edited the post, I can't rely on punctuation. the user is free to add to the text. I am wondering how WYSIWYG HTML editors do it. they pin point exactly where the user edited the text.

Answer (score 0):

To display the list as a sentence you could use string.Join(",", sentence.ToArray()), to join your string element in the list.

You would have to add a sentence separator(some special character) which would help you identify the sentence changed.

You can again fill up your List using <variable>.Split(',').ToList().

I hope this should help you, happy coding !!

Comment: getting the text to the editor is no big deal, it is figuring out the area that is being edited that is the problem. using a special character to separate the list will not work, the use can delete those characters and that would throw off the list. thanks tho.